# UV map only using half of the texture

Tags: texturing, uv, mirror

I deleted half of the mesh and used symmetrize. Only half of the texture map has UV coordinates now even though the entire head of the model is being selected. Is there a way to mirror these UV's back to where they were?

[image]

Comment: All the vertices have UV maps, they just are set on the same side of the map. You can select half the head, scale the UV on the X by -1 and move them manually into place. Hopefully someone will come along with a better answer...